# Как можно узнать количество запросов в секунду insert/select/update/delete для каждой таблицы в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Хочу сделать сбор статистики использовать ресурсов mysql, для этого нужно получать данные по отдельности по каждой таблице.

Хочу получать такие данные, как:

- insert запросы в секунду
- select запросы в секунду
- update запросы в секунду
- delete запросы в секунду
- количество медленных запросов в секунду (если такое возможно узнать)

Как это можно делать?

Comment: Начните [отсюда](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/innodb_stats.html)

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая полезная утилита [mytop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mytop). А здесь по ней вроде неплохой гайд:
https://itisgood.ru/2018/06/28/kak-ispolzovat-mytop-dlja-monitoringa-proizvoditelnosti-mysql-mariadb-v-linux/

Comment: эта штука не подсчитывает кол-во запросов для каждой отдельной таблицы. по сути она просто выводит SHOW PROCESSLIST и все

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук, но она подсчитывает количество запросов для каждой БД. Можно одним запросом раскидать таблицы по разным БД и скриптом для мультиплексора запустить по одной копии на каждую таблицу.